# how flexsurvreg plot can be interpreted for repeated time-to event model?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

am performing repeated time to event parametric model using flexsurvreg. Patients can have multiple infection events(1=event,0=no event)

```
model = flexsurvreg(Surv(START,STOP,EVENT) ~ predictor1+predictor2,data= infection,dist="weibull")

p=ggflexsurvplot(model, xlab = "Time (Months)", censor = F, conf.int = T,
                 fun = "survival")
```

I am trying to do visual predictive checks such as KM curve overlaid with model prediction and prediction interval. I was able to achieve the plot by ggflexsurvplot.  I am unable to interpret the plot.
Is KM for first event in that plot?.
Is Model fit curve for all events in that plot?
How can I interpret that plot?
How can I do meaningful other plots /tables to interpret the effect of predictors on infection event time such as probability survival curve between predictors?

Comment: Seems more a request for analytics strategy. Once you can describe the methods you will be ready to do a search for packages and functions and to themn describe where your coding approach gets stuck. Suggest that the first phase of this project should be conducted at CrossValidated.com